# Share root ("/") using Samba

Tags: windows, samba, root

So I have this old laptop running Ubuntu as a small webserver and on this one I managed to share the root with Samba so I can mount it on my Windows desktop.

Now I have bought this little pc second hand to replace that laptop and I want to do the same but for some reason I cannot get it done. I have re-installed completely and installed a fresh version of samba but did not do anything else to it.

So what I want is to mount the Ubuntu 20.04 root folder as a network drive in Windows 10, it's a local network and it will not be used from the outside. I copied the config-file that was used on the laptop to the desktop and now I can see the share on Windows but when I try to enter access is denied. Yesterday I've managed to mount and read but I couldn't write. Now I am back to the standard config again and stopped trying for now because I have no idea what I can do to make it work.

I have tried Googling it but to no helpful result unfortunately. Can anybody help me with this? I'm fully aware of the security risks but my home network is pretty secure and the server will not be used for any sensitive data or something, just to test out web-projects and run an instance of Bookstacks on Apache. Also just to mess around and learn.

Comment: Please add some more details. What do you mean by "I cannot get it done"? I understand that you can't see the Samba share from the Windows machine, but can you see it from the laptop, or not at all? Did you restart `smbd` after making modifications? Is the username the same on all three systems, or do you allow "guest" access?

Comment: Added some more info. The laptop was just to mention that I have it working on one device but couldn't get it to work on the other device. I do not need to connect the laptop to my Ubuntu as when I'm done installing all software and copy the files needed the laptop will be put out of service and might serve another use.

Comment: How do you have the share setup on the Samba server?  What did you put in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file?  Samba has to be told what it is sharing, how it is sharing and who it is sharing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found a fix, all I had to do was add 'force user = root' to the share profile. No idea why it worked before without that but it seems like that fixed it :) No idea why I haven't tried that before. Thanks for the help anyway!